# Series solution to a second-order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

### Problem:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Find a solution to
$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0$$
given
$$y(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^{k+j},\qquad k>0.$$

### A brief progress:

By differentiating the series we get
$$y'=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (k+j)a_jx^{k+j-1}\\
y''=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (k+j-1)(k+j)a_jx^{k+j-2}$$
Substituting this back in our equation we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty (k+j-1)(k+j)a_jx^{k+j}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty (k+j)a_jx^{k+j}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^{k+j+2}-\sum_{j=0}^\infty n^2a_jx^{k+j}=0$$
which simplifies to
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty[(k+j)^2-n^2]a_jx^{k+j}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^{k+j+2}=0$$

### Status:

This is where i'm stuck!

- Am I on the right track?
- How do I add the series in the last equation with $x^{k+j}$ and $x^{k+j+2}$?
- How do I find $k$ and $a_j$?

Answer (score 1):

Your last formula
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty[(k+j)^2-n^2]a_jx^{k+j}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^{k+j+2}=0$$
can be written equivalently as
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty[(k+j)^2-n^2]a_jx^{k+j}+\sum_{j=2}^\infty a_{j-2}x^{k+j}=0$$
or
$$
(k^2-n^2)a_0x^k+((k+1)^2-n^2)a_1x^{k+1}+
\sum_{j=2}^\infty\big[[(k+j)^2-n^2]a_j+a_{j-2}\big]x^{k+j}=0$$
Hence, you obtain two solutions, one for $a_0=1,a_1=0$ and another for $a_0=0,a_1=1$. Then continue recursively in each case.

For the first solution, $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$, implies that $k=\pm n$, and
$$
a_{2j+1}=0,\quad a_{2j+2}=\big(n^2-(k+2j)^2\big)a_{2j}.
$$

Comment: I've had my formula on that form before. The problem is that I can't see how to solve for $k$ and $a_j$ when the formula is on that form. Can you please specify your solution for $k$ and $a_j$? Guess I've gone totally blind on this problem :/

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment. Can you explain how you obtained your two solutions $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$ and $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ from that formula?